# Usage of preposition 'in' - St Petersburg at night

Tags: prepositions, articles

Which is the correct form of the following caption for a photo:

> - Night beauty *in* St Petersburg
> - St Petersburg night beauty

Or does the right sentence have to be "*A* night beauty in St Petersburg".

Should I use auxiliary verb here or  article (a/an)?

Comment: "Night beauty in City" sounds like a fine title to me. It doesn't necessarily need to be grammatical or a complete sentence. As a complete sentence, you might say "This photograph shows the beauty of the night in the city. Therefore I decided to call it 'city night beauty'." You don't need an article like 'a' or 'the' in a title like this.

Comment: I'm not clear if it is a specific city or just 'a city'. This will make a difference to how you say it.

Comment: *Beauty **of** the city at night* -- you will need *of* and also probably *the* -- phrasing does not mean that possessives can be formed any which way.

Comment: I would understand "Night beauty in City" as "a beautiful (girl) who typically moves about at night and has arrived in an urban place;" and "City night beauty" as, maybe, an attempt to say something of the sort of a beautiful (girl) who typically moves about the city at night." Even then the phrasing is awkward.

Comment: Thank you for comments. Under city I mean definite name of it. Like New York of something. Yeah, there is another little problem with meaning - I meant very bright beauty of city's night. But if I say 'night beauty' - somebody can understand it as if I meant a girl :)

Comment: I've tidied up the question, including a real example rather than just a generic placeholder. But could you add what the photo is actually **of**? Is it a girl, or the cityscape at night, or something else? In fact, adding a suitable example image (not necessarily one of yours, just a CC-licensed pic from Wikipedia which illustrates the caption) would help here.

Comment: @StepanPervikov Yes, _night beauty_ would unambiguously be interpreted as referring to _a_ night beauty, i.e., with _beauty_ being a count noun, whose most common meaning (when it’s not further modified) is ‘a beautiful woman’. And the word _night_ would just make it worse: it would end up meaning a lady of the night, which is a prostitute. “Night beauty” = “beautiful prostitute”. If you’re just talking about how beautiful St Petersburg looks at night, you can say something like “Beautiful St Petersburg nightscape/night-time scenery” or “Beautiful St Petersburg at night”, etc.

Comment: Well, here is the photo https://igcdn-photos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t51.2885-15/10554082_345918532280137_1777021537_n.jpg.

Answer (score -1):

Use beauteous instead:- "Beauteous night in St. Petersburg" carries no implication of attractive females, but simply suggests that the night is beautiful in St. Petersburg.

Comment: There's nothing suggetive about "beautiful night in St. Petersburg"